Multiclass casters and staves
(this started with Animists, I moved the second question here)
I think a Fighter multiclassing into a Wizard with Basic Wizard Spellcasting could prepare a staff, and expand a spell slot during presentation to give it extra charges. Similarly, if she multiclassed into Oracle, she could spend a slot during casting to reduce the charge cost.
If I am wrong, the answer can stop here.
If the base class is a prepared caster multiclassing into spontaneous or vice versa, can he do both? Spend a slot at preparation and casting?

It works
Spellcasting Archetypes says:

A spellcasting archetype allows you to use scrolls, staves, and wands in the same way that a member of a spellcasting class can.

It is hard to prove a negative, but I could not find any other limitation in the above section or at Staves.
So yes, you can add charges at preparation and reduce cost at casting if you have both spontaneous and prepared casting.
